# LWJGL Vulkan : nothing drawn when adding a second vertex buffer

Tags: java, lwjgl, vulkan

I've made a little program with lwjgl that displays a colored triangle using Vulkan, at first I was sending all the required data to my shaders through a single vertex buffer (color + position).
While knowing that it is the best practice to use only one vertex buffer I still wanted to try to send the positions and the colors through 2 different vertex buffer

To add my second vertex buffer I've created it the same way I created the first, I then added a binding and attributed the second attribute to it like this :

```
VkVertexInputBindingDescription.Buffer bindingDescriptor = VkVertexInputAttributeDescription.calloc(2)
    .binding(0)
    .stride(2 * 4)
    .inputRate(VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX);
//I added this
bindingDescriptor.binding(1)
    .stride(3 * 4)
    .inputRate(VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX);

VkVertexInputAttributeDescription.Buffer attributeDescription = VkVertexInputAttributeDescription.calloc(2)
    .get(0)
    .binding(0)
    .location(0)
    .format(VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT)
    .offset(0);
attributeDescription.get(1)
    //changed the binding from 0 to 1
    .binding(1)
    .location(1)
    .format(VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT)
    .offset(0);
```

then in the definition of the render pass I've added my second vertex buffer to the buffer submitted to `vkCmdBindVertexBuffers` like this :

```
LongBuffer offsets = memAllocLong(2);
offsets.put(0, 0L);
//added this
offsets.put(1, 0L);
LongBuffer pBuffers = memAllocLong(2);
pBuffers.put(0, verticesBuf);
//added this
pBuffers.put(1, colorBuf);
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(renderCommandBuffers[i], 0, pBuffers, offsets);
```

The problem is that when I add my second vertex buffer nothing is displayed anymore, the only thing left is my background color
Am I missing something ? Is there something special to do to use multiple vertex buffers ?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the code as I don't know the *lwjgl*, but in attribute description You specify attribute for the first and second attributes with `get(0)` and `get(1)` functions. But You don't do the same for binding description. Are You sure You are not "overwriting" the description of the first binding with the description of the second binding? Instead of `bindingDescriptor.binding(1)` shouldn't You write something like this `bindingDescriptor.get(1).binding(1)`??

Comment: Thank you sir ! You solved my problem ! I should definitely be more focused on my code ^^

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help ;-).